# Let f be continuous. By EVT there exists a c such that f(c)=supx f(x). Show that f is not injective.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I am given a continuous function f in an interval [a,b].

To show that f is not injective, should I consider the definition of the extreme value theorem? I am not sure how to show that it is not one to one.

[image]

Comment: Draw a triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is injective, then $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$.  Look at the closed interval $[a,c]$, then Intermediate Value Theorem says that $f$ hits any value between $f(a)$ and $f(c)$.  Since $c\in{}(a,b)$, then WLOG we can assume $f(a)<f(b)<f(c)$, so for some $d\in{}(a,c)$ we have $f(d)=f(b)$, but $b\neq{}d$, so $f$ is not injective.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is injective then $f(a)$, $f(b)$ and $f(c)$ are pairwise different. Assume WLOG that $f(a)<f(b)<f(c)$. Continuity of $f$ implies that $ft)=f(b)$ for some $t\in(a,c)$.